Computing a limit involving products
Problem definition
For $C$ finite, let $\{\ell_k(c)\}_{c=1}^C$ be a probability mass function at time $k$, i.e. $\ell_k(c)\in[0,1]$ and $\sum_{c=1}^C \ell_k(c)=1$. Let $\{p_0(c)\}_{c=1}^C$ be a prior probability mass function. Finally, consider the non-normalized posterior at time $K$
\begin{equation}
\Lambda_K(c)\triangleq \left(\prod_{k=1}^K \ell_k(c)\right) p_0(c) \qquad c=1,\dots,C
\end{equation}
and its normalized version
\begin{equation}
p_K(c)\triangleq \frac{\Lambda_K(c)}{\sum_{\nu=1}^C \Lambda_K(\nu)} \qquad c=1,\dots,C
\end{equation}
I'm looking for some condition on the sequence $\{\{\ell_k(c)\}_{c=1}^C\}_{k=1}^K$ so that, as $K\to\infty$, the normalized posterior $p_K(c)$ converges to a probability mass function entirely concentrated over a single class $c^*$ ($p_K(c)=1$ if $c=c^*$ and $p_K(c)=0$ otherwise).
For simplicity, assume that $\ell_k(c)>0$ for all $k$ and $c$ and assume that $p_0(c)>0$ for all $c$.
My attempt
To get $p_K(c)=1$ if $c=c^*$ and $p_K(c)=0$ otherwise, it must be true that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{K\to \infty} \Lambda_K(c^*) \gg \lim_{K\to \infty} \Lambda_K(c) \qquad \forall c \neq c^*
\end{equation}
or, equivalently, that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{K\to \infty} \frac{\Lambda_K(c^*)}{\Lambda_K(c)}=\infty \qquad \equiv\\
\lim_{K\to \infty} \log\left(\frac{\Lambda_K(c^*)}{\Lambda_K(c)}\right)=\infty \qquad \equiv\\
\lim_{K\to \infty} \log\left(\frac{p_0(c^*)}{p_0(c)}\right) + \sum_{k=1}^K \log\left(\frac{\ell_k(c^*)}{\ell_k(c)}\right)=\infty \qquad \equiv\\
\lim_{K\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^K \log\left(\frac{\ell_k(c^*)}{\ell_k(c)}\right)=\infty \\
\end{aligned}
 \qquad \forall c \neq c^*
\end{equation}
At this point I get stuck. The problem is that the condition $\lim_{K\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^K \log\left(\frac{\ell_k(c^*)}{\ell_k(c)}\right)=\infty$ does not tell me so much. I would like to know if we can further simplify the condition and get some intuitive result.

A sufficient condition for convergence to the unit mass might be $l_k(c^*) > l_k(c) \hspace{2mm} \forall k \geq 1, \forall c \neq c^* (Equ. 1)$. You could construct an easy example as $l_k(c^*) = \frac{2}{3}, \hspace{4mm} l_k(c) = \frac{1}{3(C-1)} \hspace{2mm} \forall k \geq 1, \forall c \neq c^*$. To make things even simpler, consider C = 2, giving you two observations in your sample space, and we could set $c^*$ as 1, so we have $l_k(1) = \frac{2}{3}, \hspace{4mm} l_k(2) = \frac{1}{3(C-1)} = \frac{1}{3}$. We can check one third and two thirds sum to 1 in a probability mass function.
This is a deterministic example that $(Equ. 1)$ holds. Your example has varying $l_k(c^*)$ and $l_k(c), \hspace{2mm} c \neq c^*$ in $k$. For a more involved example, consider $l_k(c^*) \xrightarrow{} v^*, \hspace{2mm} l_k(c) \xrightarrow{} v_{c}, \hspace{2mm} \forall k \geq 1, \forall c \neq c^*$.
This gives room that sometimes $l_k(c^*) < l_k(c)$ for some $ k \geq 1, \forall c \neq c^*$. However, since the limit of the $l_k(c), \hspace{2mm} \forall c \in C$ is $v_c$, and since $l_k(c^*)$ tends to a limit $v^*$ that is strictly greater than $v_c \hspace{2mm} \forall c \in C$, then $\exists N \hspace{2mm} s.t. \forall n \geq N$ the normalised posterior distributions will accumulate more mass in outcome $c^*$. This starts assuredly once $k > N$ and where $l_k(c^*) > l_k(c)$. Any example that satisfies this has posteriors converging to unit mass.
The exact conditions for convergence might be more subtle, or simpler. My guess is the latter example above is good enough: the observation $c^*$ needs to have $l_k(c^*)$ converge to something greater than what the $l_k(c)$ converge to (assuming $l_k(c)$ converge) as $k \xrightarrow{} \infty$. If you have this condition, and it is pretty general, you get the convergence to unit mass.
Edit: readability
